# Spring Security logout success url to another host

Tags: redirect, spring-security, logout

is that possible to make Spring Security 3.2.7.RELEASE redirect user to another host after logout? I can't force it to use another host. I'm using some kind of SSO access system and that might be a problem.

Example:
My app is started on http://myAppUrl:8080/webapp1/
Users access it through http://ssoAccess:80/webapp1/ and that leads to real url, but in browser i still see ssoAccess url all the time (like some kind of proxy)

I want to make logout button from http://myAppUrl:8080/webapp1/logout.xhtml
to logout then redirect to http://ssoAccess:80/appList

When logout-success-url is set to "http://ssoAccess:80/appList" it redirects to http://ssoAccess:80/webapp1/http://ssoAccess:80/appList which is obviously not correct url returning 404.

I tried logout-success-handler as well, but still same problem. I also tried to make @Controller that has method returning "redirect:http://ssoAccess:80/appList" on endpoint that is pointed by logout-success-url. Still no luck.

I'm also using JSF.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple trick is that you create a logout.xhtml page in webapp1 that redirect's to appList.

logout.xhtml:

```
<script language="javascript">
    window.location.href = "http://ssoAccess:80/appList"
</script>
```

Comment: It works, thanks for help, but redirect page varies on different environments. Is there a way to take this value from *.properties or jsf/spring bean? I tried using standard placeholders and it unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: @voidmat you can pass parameters. For example `http://myAppUrl:8080/webapp1/logout.xtml?http://ssoAccess:80/appList` and in logout.xhtml use this: `window.location.href = window.location.search.substr(1)`